# eclipse + xdebug 2.2.1 debug opens outdated file

Tags: xdebug, easyphp

I updated EasyPhp to version 12,

if I set a breakpoint in Eclipse to **/work/abc.php**, during debug
Eclipse opens up a **c:\www\work\abc.php**

Then when if I modify /work/abc.php Eclipse still shows the old file!

Xdebug 2.2.1 is more stable, but what is this local file copy thing?
[image]
here is the php.ini

```
;Xdebug
zend_extension = "${path}\php\php5314x120809150232\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.default_enable=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart = false
xdebug.dump_globals=1
xdebug.dump=COOKIE,FILES,GET,POST,REQUEST,SERVER,SESSION
xdebug.dump.SERVER=REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD,REQUEST_URI
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.show_mem_delta=1
xdebug.collect_includes=1
xdebug.collect_vars=1
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.auto_trace=0
xdebug.trace_options=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.trace_output_dir="${path}\xdebug\trace"
xdebug.trace_output_name="trace.%t"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="${path}\xdebug\profiler"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%s.%t"
;/Xdebug
```

I'm using Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: 3.0.2 ( Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.1)

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more? - do you modify the file while the request is still active (only stopped by the debugger)? - do you modify the file in eclipse or via another tool?

Comment: i only modify with eclipse when no request is in progress(as in debugger doesn't wait for me to press F8continue)

Comment: seems like your workflow is correct...strange, i never had this with xdebug running remotely on an apache. definitely sounds like a cache problem

Answer (score 0):

When you work remotely you need to map the remote file to a local directory. Maybe Eclipse tries to open the file locally and when you change the file it doesn't know that it has to update the file remotely? I don't know much Eclipse but I use Komodo with php and xdebug.